# NodeJS , sequelize catch error return undefined ,

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I used Sequelize + Node , So i want to write Sequelize Validation part in separate service class. When i run this code result set to  "undefined",please help me resolve this.

**userController.js**

```
 let userData = request.body;
   


    let result = await userService.createUser(userData);
  console.log(result);
```

**user.service.js**

```
module.exports.createUser = async (userData) => {

    let user = {
        first_name: userData.first_name,
        last_name: userData.last_name,
        email: userData.email,
        password: userData.password
    };


    await User.create(user).then(result => {
        console.log('success');
        return result;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error');
        return 'test';
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result code is `undefined` because the `createUser` function don't return any, you should use await/async properly. Try this:

```
module.exports.createUser = async (userData) => {

    let user = {
        first_name: userData.first_name,
        last_name: userData.last_name,
        email: userData.email,
        password: userData.password
    };


    try {
        const result = await User.create(user);
        console.log('success');
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error');
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much . It works now . I added myown code . https://snipboard.io/k8UT6c.jpg Then I got  those errors https://snipboard.io/wj3eK6.jpg

Comment: You must check the input data (request.body) because it seems that several values like `first_name` and `email` are empty.